# .htaccess replace url parameter value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL that with some parameters. One of the parameters called 'lang' and it looks like this:

```
https://example.com/example1/?id=1&lang=en
```

I want to redirect all the current URL with lang=en to lang=gb

```
https://example.com/example1/?id=1&lang=gb
```

**Note:** the `example1` folder is an example and it doesn't a constant variable.
every URL contains a different folder name.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site is not a code-writing service, you are expected to make an attempt yourself first of all, and then show us that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:(.*&)?)lang=en(?:(&.*)?)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1lang=gb%2 [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only to change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as expected. That prevents nasty caching issues.

In general you should prefer to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. Distributed configuration files (".htaccess") should only be used if no other alternative exist. They come with a number of disadvantages.